# VoiceClient.play() doesn't play any audio

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I am trying to make a music bot in discord.py, but whenever I tried to play audio using VoiceClient.play(), it never played anything, just stayed in the voice channel.

```
async def play(ctx):
    for VoiceClient in client.voice_clients:
        if VoiceClient.guild == ctx.guild:
            await VoiceClient.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'))
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'⬅  {ctx.author.mention},  I am now playing that song.', color=0x51BDEF)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

There weren't any error messages either, just doesn't play anything

Comment: Why is the VoiceClient named as class it's just a object. Also did you load opus library?

Comment: I don't think so.. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Try replacing your for loop to `voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` then you just have to write `voice.play(discord.FFmpePCMAudio('song.mp3'))` and send your message. /!\ You'll have to import `get` by adding `from discord.utils import get`

Comment: man its been over a year after i posted that you'd think i wont need anymore help